# Was there an attempt to create artifical language that computers understand well when spoken by human?

Tags: constructed-language

While now many smartphones feature the "assistant" of one or another kind, and even have dedicated buttons to invoke them, the experience with these assistants, at least for me, is invariably frustrating. Even short, trivial phrases must be repeated multiple times to be understood. I have experimented with various languages talking with my phone and finally thought, if it cannot do with human language, why cannot we have a specialized one computer understands?

I thought what could make the life of the smartphone easier. Words should have recoverable meaning even if pronounced somewhat wrongly. Minor errors should never result in a valid word with different meaning. Written and spoken forms must have simple and consistent rules for translation in between. Phonemes should be restricted to the subset common in many widespread languages, do not expecting something I have now clue how to pronounce.

Have this ever been attempted?

Comment: phonemes should be restricted? Every language has it own phonemes to differentiate meaning. if you do not represent the [i] in English for example, you cannot express: The bit of the ship that was missing was the bit that was hit. So the common subset idea just does not work. Sorry.

Comment: Rhis depends on speech recognition software, Whisper is quite well

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there was, and the project went a quite a long way to implement it. It was named [Robot Interaction Language (Roila)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Interaction_Language) and their website https://www.roila.org is still up (10 years after the completion of the research project).

Comment: Thanks, reading about it.

Comment: P.S. Roila is on-topic on [conlang.se]: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roila

Comment: Was not aware about that community.

Comment: And it limits the phonemes to a common subset of phonemes between languages?

Comment: @Lambie: No, it selects the vowel phonemes from American English and has a strange bias in this respect. But it simplifies to a 5-vowel system.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to set the OP straight on this. Like I said above, if you ignore the [i] in English, there's a lot you cannot express and that phoneme/sound does not exist in Spanish, for example.